# How can I convert the following coordinates to something I can put in Google Earth?

Tags: coordinates, latitude-longitude

I've tried converting the following lat/long data into Google Earth but the intersection doesn't show up on my map when I try entering them.

What does N87° 40'20"E convert to?

What does N1° 49'33"W convert to?

[image: radius compass site map]

**UPDATE**

This is the only other map I have of the area. The zoom in is located using the orange square in the image below. Not finding a control point, could be off the map as it seems this is piecemeal and a custom map from the original.

[image: site map]

Comment: Looks like bearing and distance to me, but without knowing where the source point is, it may not be enough to generate a real world coordinate.

Comment: I agree, these aren't positional coordinates but bearings and distances used to draw in boundary lines.  You'd need to know a point of origin (often shown in notes on a lot/boundary plan like the partial one in your screenshot)

Comment: You might visit http://sdgis.sandag.org/ and search for parcel No 2641015400. The site provides latlon coordinates at the mouse position. They also offer data for download at http://www.sangis.org/download/index.html, but you are requested for login.

Comment: According to this guide for San Diego County Parcel Identification:  https://arcc.sdcounty.ca.gov/Documents/parcel-map-guide.pdf  the parcel consists of Book-Block-Parcel, in your case this half of the page is missing the Book which is likely on the other half, so your Parcel would be ###-101-54.

Comment: if you know the street address, then you could find the parcel number: https://arcc.sdcounty.ca.gov/Pages/Property-Sales.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't believe you can calculate a *position* from these values.  These look to be bearings and distances - a direction around a circle from a *known* location.

The known location could be anywhere in the world, and the boundary lines are drawn in the direction and distance listed from that known location.  These are used to create lot boundaries.

Basically it's something like this (probably over-simplified).  The `N` represents the compass bearing the values are based on.  I believe these are usually either North or South (but have seen some with East and West).  In this case, as it's `N` for North, the angles are to the `E` East or `W` West of that North bearing.  The `328.81` is the distance from your known location, in the direction of your bearing.

The point of intersection needs to be known.  Usually a lot plan will have an origin point to base the rest of the lines from, and then subsequent lines are started from the end of the previous line.  If you don't know where that origin point is, then you may be out of luck.

[image]

It's been a very long time since I've input boundaries from plans like this, and I only ever did it while learning, so I may be wrong with some of it, but I think I got the basics right here.

Comment: I agree and would add that a bearing can be any combination of N#E, N#W, S#E, S#W.  The bearing is in Degrees/Minutes/Seconds but may be converted to Decimal (N87°40'20"E = N87.67222222E) or even Degree-Minute decimal  (N87°40.33333333)...  but it is still a bearing and requires a known starting point which is likely described further away from the lines you are sharing here.  Think of it like like drawing a square where you never lift up your pencil... you have to start with your pencil on the paper somewhere.  See http://academic.brooklyn.cuny.edu/geology/leveson/core/linksa/comp.html

Comment: @Tiger Danky follow your lines to the South or West to locate the starting point.

Comment: thx everyone. makes so much more sense now.

Comment: @Tiger Danky so did you find the start point in your file?

Comment: @kttii I posted the only other image I have access to. Think that the map is lacking the origin point.

Comment: Your new image is [here on google maps](https://goo.gl/maps/vzUGzXi1WpT2) - all you need to do is find a known coordinate from the location map and your image and use the bearings and distances to locate your area of interest (if it's not already easily identifiable from google maps).

Answer (score -2):

I take it that looks like standard latitude and longitude, in degrees - minutes - seconds (N87 degrees, 40 minutes and 20 seconds). Apparently this can be converted to decimal using the following:

Decimal Degrees = Degrees + minutes/60 + seconds/3600

Though I'm unsure if this is correct in your particular case (and also because I haven't done that in a while).

Comment: N*blah*E and N*blah*W are not simple DMS designations.